# Combine/Converting many parallel lines to one single line using ModelBuilder of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, line, merge

I am working with railway generalization by using ArcGIS ModelBuilder and my solution needs to involve that software. I need to "Combine/Convert" many parallel lines together into one wherever they are close to each other.

Beside use Merge Divided Road tool, does anybody know how to "Merge" many lines to one?

The left data should become the right.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a way to achieve this task?

Answer (score 3):

The tool that I would try on this data is [Integrate](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm):

> Analyzes the coordinate locations of feature vertices among features
>   in one or more feature classes. Those that fall within a specified
>   distance of one another are assumed to represent the same location and
>   are assigned a common coordinate value (in other words, they are
>   colocated). The tool also adds vertices where feature vertices are
>   within the x,y tolerance of an edge and where line segments intersect.

Answer (score 0):

create a buffer on each line and dissolve them to one polygon (select the size of the buffer accordingly). Then use the polygon to centerline tool and you are ready.